# How to change a @State public var value in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, button, uibutton, swiftui

In SwiftUI, I have

```
@State public var utilisateur = ""
@State var connected = false
```

Here, I have a TextField to set value of `utilisateur`.

```
TextField("nom.prenom", text: $utilisateur)
```

Then, if `utilisateur` is not `""`, i did this :

```
if self.connected{

                       Text("Connecté en tant que \(utilisateur)")
                   .padding()
                   .background(Color(red:0.3,green:0.8,blue:0.3))
                       .foregroundColor(.white)
                }

if (!(self.utilisateur=="")){

                    Button(action: {self.connected.toggle()}) {
                        self.connected ? Text("Se déconnecter") : Text("Se connecter")
                    //                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    }
                                    .padding()
                    .background(self.connected ? Color(.red) : Color(red:0.0,green:0.4,blue:0.7))
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                }
```

What I want is to delete `utilisateur` value when the user click on `Se déconnecter`.

I try many possibilities but no one works...

```
if !(self.connected){
                    $utilisateur=""
                }
```

```
if !(self.connected){
                    utilisateur=""
                }
```

```
if !(self.connected){
                    self.utilisateur=""
                }
```

```
if !(self.connected){
                    self.$utilisateur=""
                }
```

Do someone know how to do this ?

Comment: Just a note: you can skip parentheses in `if` statements in Swift. Instead of writing `if (!(self.utilisateur=="")){` you can do `if self.utilisateur != "" {`. Your code will be more readable this way.

Comment: `!utilisateur.isEmpty` is the better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right one you should be using is `self.utilisateur = ""` add this line to your `Button`'s action block. Here's the working code you need for doing this:

```
struct CV: View {
    @State private var utilisateur = ""
    @State private var connected   = false
    @State private var buttonTitle = "connect"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Connect to??", text: $utilisateur)
            if connected {
                Text("Connected to \(utilisateur)")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color(red:0.3,green:0.8,blue:0.3))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            if !utilisateur.isEmpty {
                Button(action: {
                    if self.buttonTitle == "connect" {
                        self.buttonTitle = "disconnect"
                    } else {
                        self.utilisateur = ""
                    }
                    self.connected.toggle()
                }) {
                    Text(buttonTitle)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .padding()
                .background(connected ? Color(.red) : Color(red:0.0,green:0.4,blue:0.7))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case, once I click to connect the peudo will be deleted. What I want is that the pseudo will only be deleted on "disconnect" click

Comment: I only see one button in the code. Did you forget to add the `Disconnect` button? Or am I missing something? Or are you saying about the same button with 2 different titles?

Comment: The same button connect and disconnect : `self.connected ? Text("be disconnected") : Text("Be connected")`

Comment: Although I'm a bit confused about you flow I've updated to a sensible solution for your problem. Check this out.

Comment: It works very well! Thank you :)
I just add `self.buttonTitle = "connect"` in `else` to reset the value